# Find the solution of a complex equation

Tags: numerical-methods

Find the solution $x$ of the equation 
$$
\frac{{Ae^{\frac{{Cx}} {{{\left( {1 - x}\right)}^{D} }}} }}{{1 + Bx}} = x
$$
where $A$,$B$,$C$ and $D$ are the constant coefficients. 
If the solution of above equation can't be obtained, I want to ask to find the solution x of the equation 
$$
\frac{{Ae^{Cx} }}{{1 + Bx}} = x
$$
where $A$,$B$,$C$ are the constant coefficients.

Comment: I had tried to use the Fixed point method, but I didn't get the solution. Maybe I didn't understand the Fixed point method. I want to get the algebraic solution of the equations.

Comment: Sorry to Dr. Sonnhard Graubner, I didn't reply to you in time. I received the email but I wrongly regarded it as spam.

Comment: Have you tried using Maple?

Comment: No hope for analytical solution. Numerical methods only.

Comment: `Maple` and `Mathematica` can't find analytical solution for first and second equation.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Do you need an analytical solution (i.e. x in terms of A,B,C,D)? Or could you be satisfied with an algorithm that, provided real values for A,B,C,D , will provide you a solution "x"?

Comment: I need an analytical solution (i.e. x in terms of A,B,C,D).